# How to get a single doc with React/Firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

All I want to do is to get a row (so called 'doc') from a data base.

so far, I have tried:

all with the 'aref'

```
  const aref = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("polja")
    .where("id", "==", match.params.id);
  console.log(aref);

  function getIt() {
    const item = [];
    setLoading(true);
    aref.get().then((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data();
      setItem(item);
      console.log(item);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getIt();
  }, []);
```

this gave the following error:

[image: error]

[image: db structure]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your Firestore structure

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get a single document, you must specify the document ID:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("polja").doc(documentId).get().then((snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.data())
}).catch((e) => console.log(e))
```

Also you should not use `.where()` to get just a single document, but there is an issue I found in your original code.

If you look carefully, the parameter in `.where()` is a string `"match.params.id"`. That seems to be a dynamic value being fetched from somewhere else. Please remove the quotes and try again.

```
firebase.firestore().collection("polja").where("id", "==", match.params.id).get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

Try adding a catch block as shown which might help catch any errors. Make sure your security rules also allow you to fetch the data.
Also if any error is logged in the console, share a screenshot of it.

Comment: thank you Dharmaraj! I edited my original question and added the screenshots You requested. So far, no cigar...

Comment: @ydrea can you run my code and tell if anything is not working ?

Comment: I have. Got a Uncaught (in promise) Error: FIRESTORE (8.4.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state

Comment: @ydrea that's strange, would you please share screenshot of your updated code as well as the error itself?

Comment: now I see a thing with an arrow in the console log. do you know how to turn it into an array? :)

Comment: @ydrea you might want to try `console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.data()))` It will give you a cleaner view

Comment: you mean doc.data()

Comment: @ydrea yes I was giving an example of single document case.

Answer (score 6):

To get single document form firebase firestore you should first know if you are using the modular firebase 9.+ version or firebase version < 9.

In new modular firebase firestore(version 9.+) it should be like this:

```
import { getFirestore, collection, query, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore'
async read(id) {
  const firestore = getFirestore()
  const docRef = doc(firestore, this.collectionPath, id)
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)

  const data = docSnap.exists() ? docSnap.data() : null

  if (data === null || data === undefined) return null

  return { id, ...data }
}
```

If you are using not modular Firebase firestore( < version 9) then the same function should look something like this:

```
async read(id) {
  const result = await (await firestore())
    .collection(this.collectionPath)
    .doc(id)
    .get()

  const data = result.exists ? result.data() : null

  if (data === null || data === undefined) return null

  return { id, ...data }
}
```